# Flash action script, how to control 3 buttons with 3 movie clips respectively

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In my flash file, I have three buttons. And I need to control three movie clips respectively with each button. However, when I test it, just right after test window has been initialized, all three movie clips playing automatically without me clicking the button. Here is my code:

```
dropper_button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dropper1); 

function dropper1 (event:MouseEvent):void{
    reaction_clip1.play();
}

dropper_button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dropper2); 

function dropper2 (event:MouseEvent):void{
    reaction_clip2.play();
}

dropper_button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dropper3); 

function dropper3 (event:MouseEvent):void{
    reaction_clip3.play();
}
```

I'm not sure where my code got wrong. Any advice would be great. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

the movieclips must have stop(); on frame 1.. you can do it in your fla or in your code like this in your first lines:

```
reaction_clip1.stop();
reaction_clip2.stop();
reaction_clip3.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly stop the `MovieClips` as they will play by default. You can do this by adding a `stop()` to the first frame of each `MovieClip`, or you could stop each one in the frame where you set up your listeners:

```
reaction_clip1.stop();
reaction_clip2.stop();
reaction_clip3.stop();

dropper_button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dropper1); 

function dropper1 (event:MouseEvent):void{
    reaction_clip1.play();
}

dropper_button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dropper2); 

function dropper2 (event:MouseEvent):void{
    reaction_clip2.play();
}

dropper_button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dropper3); 

function dropper3 (event:MouseEvent):void{
    reaction_clip3.play();
}
```